# Cannot add temporarily data to instance without saving on database Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a set of *Consequences* and this consequences has a *likes*
ManyToManyField attribute that stores all the users that have like the consequence.

What i want to archive is to add to the consequences an extra temporal attribute call *isLiked*

So later on the template I can add a data-attribute to the html indicating that the user of the request has liked already X consequences.

I am trying to do it with this approach:

views.py

```
def list_consequences(request, proponsal_id):
    try:

        consequences: [Consequence] = Consequence.objects.filter(of_proponsal=proponsal_id)

        user_likes =request.user.likes_consequences.get_queryset()

        union = consequences | user_likes

        for consequence in union:
            aux =consequences.get(pk=consequence.pk)
            aux.isLiked=True


        pros: Consequence = consequences.filter(efecto=Consecuencia.PRO)
        against: Consequence = consequences.filter(efecto=Consecuencia.AGAINST)

        template = loader.get_template('participation/consequences.html')


        context = {
            'pros': pros,
            'against': against,
            'is_user_authenticated': str(request.user.is_authenticated).lower(),
        }
        return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

    except Consequence.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("The consequence with id doesn't exist")
```

So later on the template i can do this:

consequences.html

```
...
{% for pro  in pros %}
<button data-is-liked={{pro.isLiked}}> icon</button>
{% endfor %}
...
```

Someone know how I could do this?

Thanks in advance

Django version : 2.0

Python : 3.6.5

Comment: why doing it temporarily instead of saving it ?

Comment: cause I just need it for the purpose of the template, to put an icon on a different color in base of if the user has already marked as like or not

Comment: and I already save the consequences that the user has like, the problem is that i have to merge the consequences of the existent proponsal and the consequences that the user has liked , and those that coincide mark them as isLiked

Comment: You could use `session` to do it.

Comment: I just check fast the documentation and it looks you cannot store arrays, but also in the case I could do so, I will have the same problem, cause on the template i would have to do the join somehow

Comment: So Basically you want to check whether a user has liked a `Pro` right? that's what you send `pros: Consequence = consequences.filter(efecto=Consecuencia.PRO)

`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172452/discussion-between-roberto-fernandez-and-lemayzeur).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it in this way:

```
def _getConsequences(user: User, proponsal_id):
    consequences: [consequence] = Consequence.objects.filter(of_proponsal=proponsal_id)
    user_likes = user.like_consequence.get_queryset()
    pros: Consequence = consequences.filter(efect=Consecuencia.PRO)

    union = pros & user_likes
    pro_extra_data = []
    for pro in pros:
        if pro in union:
            pro.isLiked = True
        else:
            pro.isLiked = False
        pro_extra_data.append(pro)

    #... same procedure for contra_extra_data


    return pro_extra_data, contra_extra_data
```